# Where Azure SQL, Synapse SQL data physically stored?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

Where does Synapse SQL (dedicated pool, i.e. warehouse) data physically actually stored in?  Data lake (i.e. ADLS2)?  Or any other Azure storage?

I mean it has to be within the data lake since they say Data Lake is central repo that contains "all" of your data, right?

Please correct/confirm with explanation.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for Dedicated SQL Pools (here is [another post on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72448670/where-is-data-physically-stored-in-azure-synapse-dedicated-sql-pool?rq=2))

Warehouse (or Lake Database) data is stored in the root container of your workspace. This container is defined when the workspace is created. You can find the value in the Azure Portal on the Overview page for the workspace:

[image]

You can view the underlying files in Storage Explorer:

[image]

1. Workspace name
2. Lake database name (.db)
3. Lake table name

Comment: Thanks Joel Cochran.  For clarification - does "...data is stored in the root container..." mean that the data are stored in ADLS2 data lake?  I have impression that "all of the data" is stored in ADLS2 (or other Azure storage like BLOB, etc.), period.

Comment: It's the ADLS Gen2 account associated with the Synapse workspace.